# Update Query in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need  to write an update query and I am not getting the syntax to move data from table  `emp1` to `emp2` where city = 'blore'

```
table name -->Emp1
empID name  City 
1     aaa    chennai
2     xyz    blore
3     asds   chennai
4     vvv   blore
5     aaa   chennai
6     yyy   blore

table name -->Emp2
empID name  
1     aaa    
2     xyz    
3     asds   
4     vvv   
5     aaa   
6     yyy
```

Comment: move or update, I cant get what you really mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Emp2 (Name)
       SELECT Name FROM Emp1 WHERE City = 'blore'

DELETE FROM Emp1 WHERE City = 'blore'
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual question and desired results are not very clear. I'll take a guess:

```
UPDATE Emp2 
SET Emp2.name = Emp1.name
FROM Emp1
INNER JOIN Emp2
ON Emp1.empID = Emp2.empID
WHERE Emp1.City = 'blore';
```

You may consider adding an additional WHERE clause to limit the actual update, but you didn't specify whether name was nullable in either table. So it might be this...

```
AND Emp1.name <> Emp2.name
```

...or it might be this...

```
AND COALESCE(Emp1.name, 'some not possible natural value') 
 <> COALESCE(Emp2.name, 'some not possible natural value')
```

...or you might only need COALESCE on one side.